# What happened to the 'anti-magic' coffer?

Tags: forgotten-realms, legend-of-drizzt

At the end of [Passage to Dawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passage_to_Dawn), Regis uses an "*anti-magic*" coffer to suppress Crenshinibon's attack and ultimately bring down the magic tower. This coffer seems to be incredibly powerful considering it can stop the, albeit weakened, Crenshinibon. That being said, the coffer seems to just disappear from the story and by the beginning of The Silent Blade, the next book in succession, Crenshinibon is being held by Drizzt seemingly without the coffer. I say seemingly without the coffer because Wulfgar can feel its power just standing in close proximity to Drizzt, and then throughout the book, Crenshinibon is calling weak-minded evil creatures to himself which, had he still been in the coffer, would seem to be impossible based on what little we know of the power of the coffer.

Both my brother (who originally noticed this odd omission) and I acknowledge that we could simply use our imagination regarding the missing coffer or the potential that as Crenshinibon regained its strength, the coffer lost its ability to fully suppress the artifact, but we are wondering if we missed something or if it is just not explained.